# XSLT preceding-sibling usage

Tags: xml, xaml, xslt

I need to connect ellipses with each other in a XAML canvas using lines.I managed to get everything working except it loops 14 times instead of 13 times. It should skip every 14th , how can I do this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="//stimulus/timestamp[@counter &lt; 33]/measurement">
            <xsl:variable name="firstLeft" select="115 + ((./@contact-point - 2) * 50)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="firstTop" select="((1500 - (./@value)) div 3)"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="MeasurementLoop">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="./@value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="./@contact-point"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="stimulus" select="../../@value"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="timestamp" select="../@counter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:if test="position()!=1>
                <xsl:variable name="secondLeft" select="(115 + (preceding-sibling::*[1]/@contact-point - 2) * 50)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="secondTop" select="(1500 - (preceding-sibling::*[1]/@value)) div 3"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="draw-line">
                    <xsl:with-param name="x1" select="$firstLeft"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="x2" select="$secondLeft" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="y1" select="$secondTop"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="y2" select="$firstTop"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>


        </xsl:for-each>



<xsl:template name="MeasurementLoop">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:param name="pos"/>
        <xsl:param name="stimulus"/>
        <xsl:param name="timestamp"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="draw-ellipse">
            <xsl:with-param name="left" select="115 + (($pos - 2) * 50)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="top" select="(1500 - $value) div 3" />
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$pos - 2"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="stimulus" select="$stimulus"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="timestamp" select="$timestamp"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```

Sample of XML:

```
<stimulus value="beloof">
            <timestamp counter="0" milli-seconds="7.8125">
                <measurement contact-point="3" value="354.359"/>
                <measurement contact-point="4" value="220"/>
                <measurement contact-point="5" value="356.41"/>
                <measurement contact-point="6" value="400"/>
                <measurement contact-point="7" value="369.744"/>
                <measurement contact-point="8" value="481.538"/>
                <measurement contact-point="9" value="601.026"/>
                <measurement contact-point="10" value="024.103"/>
                <measurement contact-point="11" value="436.41"/>
                <measurement contact-point="12" value="396.923"/>
                <measurement contact-point="13" value="599.487"/>
                <measurement contact-point="14" value="205.641"/>
                <measurement contact-point="15" value="188.718"/>
                <measurement contact-point="16" value="990.769"/>
            </timestamp>
```

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples of input you have, output you want, output you get and XSLT you use to allow us to reproduce and understand the problem. Without seeing the XML you have and a clear description of the result you want it is hard to help, "the code isn't working properly" is not going to tell us what you want to achieve. I only notice your `for-each` processes `measurement` elements while your `preceding-sibling::*[1]` access any kind of preceding sibling element. So perhaps `preceding-sibling::measurement[1]` is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my post with more information :)

Comment: It's still not possible to reproduce the problem, using only the code you have posted. And even if it were, one has no idea what the "correct" result needs to be.

Comment: I cut down your stylesheet to remove the parts that aren’t included. When I ran it, I got 14 ellipses and 13 lines. The call to `draw-line` is the one that uses `preceding-sibling`, where the call to `MeasurementLoop` does not. So why do you expect one less ellipse?

Comment: When I run my code, I get 14 ellipses and 14 lines. This should be 14 ellipses and 13 lines. I think I have to add an extra condition to <xsl:if test="position()!=1> , but which one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want 14 ellipses connected with 13 lines, you either must reverse the order of the line and ellipse, or change the line condition to be about the *last* line rather than the first.

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
    <xsl:variable name="secondLeft" select="(115 + (following-sibling::*[1]/@contact-point - 2) * 50)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="secondTop" select="(1500 - (following-sibling::*[1]/@value)) div 3"/>

    <xsl:call-template name="draw-line">
        <xsl:with-param name="x1" select="$firstLeft"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="x2" select="$secondLeft" />
        <xsl:with-param name="y1" select="$secondTop"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="y2" select="$firstTop"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

When I run this on your sample input (with some modifications to cover the parts of the stylesheet you didn’t include), I get this:

```
<root>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
  <line/>
  <ellipse/>
</root>
```

Comment: You solution didn't work for me but I managed to fix it by changing the condition to: <xsl:if test="(./@contact-point - 2) !=1" > . Thank you for you help.

Comment: You must have left things out of your stylesheet, then, because it works for me the way you described.